# How to install Apache Ant to Linux (Redhat CentOS) server?

Tags: linux, ant, centos

Just as a preface, sorry if I am missing something obvious. I am mainly a PHP/Python programmer but am doing server config for a friend's startup.

I only have left to install Apache Ant on my friend's Linux VPS server (he wants to compile Android apps on server- just a note I have already somehow manged to get the JDK and LAMP that would also be necessary).

When I did some digging on how to get Ant, this was all I got that really met my needs: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#jpackage

Can someone give me some kind of push on what to do at all? Maybe a wget with the appropriate link? Anything at all is appreciated.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: The solution was to very simply run 'yum install ant'. Thanks to David W. for the info that eventually got me to this page http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-i386/ant-1.7.1-13.el6.i686.rpm.html for correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you search for the package apache-ant in your RPM database?

If you're not using your RPM for installing packages (and why wouldn't you), you can download Ant directly from [Apache](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi). (Note that there are directions for JPackage RPMs too. Just in case you change your mind about not using RPMs.

Ant is a Java program, so you must have a Java JDK installed (Ant will run under the JRE, but you couldn't build Java apps with that), and make sure that the `java` command is in your Path. However, that also means that there is no special version of the Ant binary for each platform, so it's much easier to install.

Download and extract the Ant archive to a suitable directory (`/opt` or `/usr/local` or `/usr/lib` or whatever standard you're using). Inside the archive, when unpacked, will be a `bin` directory. Those files under `bin` are mainly shell scripts (the ones that end with `*.bat` are Windows Batch files, you can ignore those). Just execute those.

I like to symbolically link those files under Apache-Ant's `bin` directory to a similar name under `/usr/local/bin` directory. That way, you don't need to put `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.3/bin` in your `$PATH`.

And that's really about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the "Short Story" section at the top of the page you referenced:

To get up and running with the binary edition of Ant quickly, follow these steps:

Make sure you have a Java environment installed, See [System Requirements](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#sysrequirements) for details.

Download Ant. See [Binary Edition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#getBinary) for details.

Uncompress the downloaded file into a directory.

Set environmental variables JAVA_HOME to your Java environment, ANT_HOME to the directory you uncompressed Ant to, and add ${ANT_HOME}/bin (Unix) or %ANT_HOME%/bin (Windows) to your PATH. See [Setup](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#setup) for details.

Optionally, from the ANT_HOME directory run ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system to get the library dependencies of most of the Ant tasks that require them. If you don't do this, many of the dependent Ant tasks will not be available. See [Optional Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks) for details and other options for the -Ddest parameter.

Optionally, add any desired Antlibs. See [Ant Libraries](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/proper.html) for a list.
Note that the links in the list above will give more details about each of the steps, should you need them. Or you can just continue reading the rest of this document.